# What do you call tiny underdeveloped segments of an orange?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang

Sometimes after peeling your orange, you notice that there are also some underdeveloped segments inside it (figure 1), or at its base (figure 2).

What do you call these tiny, underdeveloped segments, which are shown by arrows in these pictures, in (casual) English?

In Persian, we casually call them the "orange's baby". Like:

> "Oh, look! My orange has babies too."

I just could find that type 2 is seen in [navel orange](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(fruit)) as an underdeveloped twin fruit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: [What is the word for the small elements that make up an orange segment?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256497)

Comment: @BrianDonovan, do you mean that those parts shown by arrows are called "juice vesicles"?

Comment: I don't know of any commonly used casual word for this! I found someone on Reddit who called it a "[mini-orange](https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/comments/18teej/there_was_a_mini_orange_inside_my_orange/)." They're definitely not juice vesicles. I think Brian Donovan just wanted to link to a related question about orange anatomy.

Comment: Based on the [wikipedia entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_%28fruit%29) that looks very much like the relevant part of the document you linked to, it is technically a *conjoined twin* and colloquially a *navel*.

Comment: @Lawrence, thanks for your comment. Do you think that the "navel" could be applied for both types or just for type  two?

Comment: @Soudabeh As a colloquial term, it's down to custom. Taking it out of a type 1 fruit leaves a hollow that resembles a navel, so I suppose it could work for both. The major sticking point is probably whether you can see at least part of the conjoined twin externally.

Comment: I see, @Lawrence. You are right. :)

Comment: There is also some [precedence](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=103250589) for calling it a "baby orange".

Comment: @Lawrence, I read that article, yes it is referred as "baby orange". I just found this :http://ask.metafilter.com/111300/Dictionary-term-for-tiny-orange-slices.

Comment: @Lawrence, why don't you change your comment ( i.e. "baby orange") to an answer? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [wikipedia entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_%28fruit%29#Navel_oranges) that looks very much like the relevant part of the document you linked to, it is technically a *conjoined twin* and colloquially a *navel*. There is also some [precedence](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=103250589) for calling it a *baby orange*.

> The mutation caused the orange to develop a second fruit at its base, opposite the stem, as a conjoined twin in a set of smaller segments embedded within the peel of the primary orange.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_%28fruit%29#Navel_oranges)
>
> A Presbyterian missionary came upon it in the mid-1800s. It intrigued him that not only did the orange have a bellybutton and baby orange inside — it was sweet, and had no seeds.
> [- Who Put The Navel In Navel Oranges?, npr.org](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=103250589)

However, when saying that you've eaten that portion of the fruit, it's probably more socially acceptable to say that you've eaten the *baby orange* than to say that you've eaten an *orange's navel*.

Answer (score 3):

Although oranges present different sizes and shapes varying from spherical to oblong, it generally has ten segments (*carpels*) inside.

A specificity of Navel oranges is the second cycle of *carpels* at the apex that leads to the apparition of a small orange inside the normal one.

You may then use the expression **secondary carpel(s)** when you want to refer to the underdeveloped segment(s).

Answer (score 1):

I've heard a couple of people calling them baby oranges as @Lawrence stated. Also, I heard a chef once calling them kisses, but it isn't a common term from what I've seen.